# What is the meaning of [もう１万円から計算してしまいますよ] here?

Tags: meaning

Here is an example of the type of language used at work called バイト敬語. I am quite confused as to why it is talking about the customer trying to pay the change aka friction of money?

Does it assumes the customer can not pay the change  hence saying もう１万円から.....?

> 会計時に金銭を受け取る際、「○円、お預かりします」ではなく「○円からお預かりします」と言う。
>
> 1万円からお預かりします。
>
> この場合、客が端数の細かい金額を足し合わせようと財布の中を覗き込んでいながら、どうも足りなさそうなので店員側で「もう1万円から計算してしまいますよ」と確認するニュアンスを持つ。このため「急かされている」「決め付けられている」と不快に感じる聞き手がいる([source](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E6%95%AC%E8%AA%9E))

Comment: Please cite your source and put quoted text in blockquotes.

Comment: I never thought that was the reason this から is annoying. It annoys me regardless of the timing.

Answer (score 2):

What the customer is trying to do here is to make the change a multiple of 10, 100, 1000. For example, when one needs to pay 8300, putting one banknote of 10000 yen is enough, but many people put 10000 + 3x 100 yen coins so that the change become 2000. (I've heard Westerners don't do this.)

一万円から計算してしまいますよ means "I'll calculate from 10000 yen", where calculation refers to "10000 - total". The passage claims some people feel rushed when the cashier says "一万円からお預かりします"

Comment: So basically not giving them the opportunity to get that round number they desire?

Comment: "I've heard Westerners don't do this" As a Westerner, I was raised to do this, but it isn't always possible with the coins you have on hand. Eventually everyone became accustomed to the machine doing the arithmetic, and cashiers would give you a confused stare if you tried to "help" them in all but the most obvious cases. (Now it's getting to the point where paying cash already looks a bit strange...)

Comment: And wat does 端数の細かい金額 mean here then ?

Comment: @user50156 Yes. I guess から gives the impression that the cashier "closes" the payment while the payer may still want to add some coins. 端数の細かい金額 is the smaller amount that 'sticks out', that is 300 yen in the above example.

Comment: So a payer puts 1000 yen. He looks for 300 yen (端数の細かい金額) for a while, then the cashier says "一万円から..." before he manages to find 3 coins, then the payer feels like the cashier starts calculating.